# Javascript uncomment code inside uncommented code

Tags: javascript

if i have a code like this...

```
var i='whatever';
/*
var x='eooo';
*/
```

There is some way to uncomment both variables without having to remove the  already present /* */ ?

This is a simple case, but often happens that I want to keep a long piece of uncommented code to use later (and this code is inside other code I need to uncomment also)

Comment: Isn't it simpler to have a conditional clause?

Comment: Add `*/` before and `/*` after the line that you want to uncomment

Comment: `/**/ uncommented /**/` Then just add/remove a space in the first comment block to toggle, e.g. `/** / commented /**/`

Comment: instead of commenting like that, you can always wrap big code blocks inside functions you never call if commenting is a huge issue for you.

Comment: When you say "uncomment" do you actually mean "comment out"?

Comment: Depending on the editor you're using, there may be a keyboard shortcut to uncomment code. Common examples include `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U` (Visual Studio, possibly others) and `Ctrl+/` (Sublime).

Comment: @Waxen this is what I was looking for, odd syntax but works anyway. I know I could use my editor for this, but I was sure there had to be another way and this is what I learned today. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `/**/` to the beginning and end of the block.  Then add a space to the end of the top comment, `/** /`, to toggle the whole block.

```
/**/
var active = true;
/**/

/** /
var commented = true;
/**/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create two comment blocks above and beneath the lines you want to use in your script.

Which means you need to add a *closing comment block delimiter* ***/** to your opening comment delimiter.

Then add an opening comment block delimiter after the lines you want un-commented **/***

```
var i='whatever';
/* [some code] */
var x='eooo';
/*
[some more code]
*/
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get this. What is "an opening comment block delimiter", and where does it appear in your example? The source for your answer contains the text `**/***`, which render in the answer as `/*`; what is that supposed to be?

Comment: `/*` is what opens a comment block (multiple lines) (thus a delimiter? correct me if I'm wrong) while `*/` is what closes a comment block (thus another delimiter). I added asterisks in my source for the styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i='whatever';
/*
var x='eooo';
*/
```

becomes

```
// var i='whatever';
// /*
// var x='eooo';
// */
```

As one poster mentioned, your editor is your friend here. In emacs, this is just `M-x comment-region`.